# Error: no member named 'stod' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I am running a code in Sublime Text 2. It shows me an error:

```
item->open = std::stod(temp);
```

The error is:

```
error: no member named 'stod' in namespace 'std'
                item->open = std::stod(temp);
```

Realised that sublime text 2 can't run c++11 code, so saw this post:http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/07/Compiling-Cpp-11-Programs-with-Sublime-Text-3.html

Posted this code in C++.sublime.build:

```
{
 "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++0x", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
 "variants":
 [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++0x '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
   }
 ]
}
```

But the error still exist. Not sure why. Need some guidance...

Update1:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Update2: Changed to c++11. No change.

```
{
 "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
 "variants":
 [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: If your compiler/library doesn't support `stod`, you can use the older C function [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) instead.

Comment: Just checking: You have included the necessary header file?

Comment: #include <string> right? i have included it..

Comment: for newer versions of gcc, the right flag is `-std=c++11`. It looks like the compiler is `clang` though.

Comment: no diff... still not working

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need at least clang/llvm 3.4 (yours is 3.3, the currently latest version, still being worked on, is 3.5). And you need the headers for libstdc++ that goes with that compiler.

Comment: Try compiling it directly on the command line, passing `-std=c++11`. If it doesn't compile, try passing also `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: command to compile on command line is g++ -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}?

Comment: Suppose your file's name is `a.cpp`, then just `g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp`.

Comment: Same error that appear in sublime appear in commandline..

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ a.cpp doesn't have the error..

Comment: @T.C. please add your answer.. will mark it right..

Comment: @MatsPetersson sorry, can you add yours an answer as well. I will upvote for u as well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the version of Clang (masquerading as `g++`, a common setup on Mac) on your computer is still using libstdc++ (GCC's C++ standard library) by default. The version of `libstdc++` that comes with OS X is ancient, and doesn't have C++11 support (and `std::stod` is a C++11 addition).

Pass `-stdlib=libc++` to your compiler to make it use Clang's standard library instead.